# What should fresh fenugreek leaves taste like?

Tags: flavor, herbs

Being a lover of dried fenugreek (methi) in Indian curries, I decided to grow fenugreek leaves.  They have the maple-like aroma I expect from the dried leaves and seeds, but the taste was very vegetal - like a bitter pea vine.  I am not a very good gardener so I am trying to discern if this is what fresh fenugreek leaves always taste like, or if I need to adjust my gardening technique to better yield tasty fenugreek leaves.

What should fresh fenugreek leaves taste like?

Comment: Good question!  I've bought them a couple times and not been impressed with them either.

Answer (score 1):

According to Masterclass, its dominant flavor should resembles maple syrup, with a hint of bitterness, sweetness, and nuttiness.

It can be incredibly bitter when eaten raw, but its meant to take on a sweeter flavor when cooked.